# Python / PyGame: Set font.render() alpha

Tags: python, pygame, label, alpha, blit

I know, how to set the alpha for a pygame.Surface, or a pygame.image. That would be:

```
surface.set_alpha(alpha)
```

but how to do that for labels, created by

```
label = font.render("I'm a label", True, [255,255,255])
```

Does anyone know this?

```
label.set_alpha(1)
```

didn't do anything to it. When I blitted it, it was just fully colored.

If you don't know, what I mean - feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

When you call font.render you are getting a `surface`. If you check the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font) it says:

"draw text on a new Surface
render(text, antialias, color, background=None) -> Surface"

The "-> Surface" means it returns a surface.

So basically, your label should work like any image in pygame. You could try this to ensure pygame is treating the label like a surface: `label = pygame.Surface((label.get_width(), label.get_height()), label)`

Also, you might have a problem with the surface being locked. To unlock it is just `pygame.Surface.unlock()` and `pygame.Surface.lock()` to lock

UPDATE:
I don't know what's wrong your missing some details because it should work.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
s = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 20)
label = font.render("hello", 0, (255,255,255))
label.set_alpha(100)
while True:
    s.fill((0,0,0))
    s.blit(label, (0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

[image]

Comment: When I write: `label = pygame.Surface(label)` I get an error, because pygame.Surface wants width and height, instead of a rendered font as params.

Comment: My apology try this `label = pygame.Surface((label.get_width(), label.get_height), label)`

Comment: Same error, cause the last "label" must be an integer. Btw, you forgot the "()" behind label.get_height

Comment: `Surface((width, height), flags=0, Surface) -> Surface` is what it says. Try giving flags a number so now try this.  `label = pygame.Surface((label.get_width(), label.get_height()), flags=0, label)`

Comment: doesn't work - it doesn't accept the last label, cause I've written "flags=.." before, and now I can't write something like "Surface=", cause that doesn't exist. if I don't write "flags=" in front of the 0, It thinks, that I mean the depth by "label".

Comment: did you use the exact code I provided and by doesn't work do you mean you get an error?

Comment: I'd been struggling with this also.  Thanks, setting anti-alias = True was the cause of my woes!